# Get text of picker in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, picker

I am using picker in Xamarin Forms and I want seleted text of picker in a string variable. Like-

```
string name = picker.SeletedItem.Text;(in WPF)
```

How to access text of picker in Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

```
picker.Items[picker.SelectedIndex];
```